Racing driver meets a blonde woman who is terminally ill
A TV drama or movie seen on TV in the late 1980s or early 1990s which I would like to find again. A racing driver and his lover or wife have promised one another to be always honest with one another, come what may. Driving, I think through France or elsewhere in Europe, he meets a blonde woman who invents things and thinks that living with fantasies and lies gives life colour. It seems she is terminally ill. He is faced with the competing values of total honesty, and the view that truth is relative. I would be grateful if anyone could identify it. 

You might be thinking about Sydney Pollack's Bobby Deerfield with Al Pacino from 1977:

Bobby Deerfield, a famous American race car driver on the European circuit, falls in love with the enigmatic Lillian Morelli, who is terminally ill.

She's not exactly blonde, though. Here's the trailer:




Many thanks. I think that might be it, not 100% sure. It is a long time since I saw it and I know my memory is not reliable. Anyway it looks like a good movie so I will try to see it.

OK, hope it's right. IIRC Lillian is quite like you've described her.

Hi Walt, That's the one. Many thanks. tas some nice shots of Lake Como too. John
